# Why is RFC 7505 (Null MX) necessary?

Tags: domain-name-system, rfc

IETF [RFC 7505](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7505.txt) describes MX records for a domain/host that explicitly should not receive email. This is accomplished by pointing the MX at the Domain Name System root. For example,

```
nomail.example.com. 86400 IN MX 0 "."
```

Why is this needed? In my understanding, explicit refutation is available by using domains under the TLD `invalid`. For example,

```
nomail.example.com. 86400 IN MX 0 "spam.invalid."
nomail.example.com. 86400 IN MX 10 "null.invalid."
```

I see that RFC 2782, DNS SRV, likewise specifies that "A Target of '.' means that the service is decidedly not available at this domain." So I suppose my question is:

Why should we use the DNS root to mean "not available" when `invalid` already serves this function?

Comment: That is not an explicit refutation, though! It's merely invalid data.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because that is not what you are supposed to be using `.invalid` for. Like `.example` it is meant for local testing and documentation.

Additionally, using `.invalid` still causes additional things to happen - additional DNS look ups and queuing on the mail server for retries for one off the top of my head.

Using the `"."` format is supposed to cause an immediate hard fail. Causing the MTA to immediately stop attempting delivery. At least that's the way the intro to the RFC reads.

Comment: Thanks. The but BCP: 32/RFC 2606 Section 2 reads " '.invalid' is intended for use in online construction of domain names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a glance are invalid."

2606 says nothing to indicate that ".invalid" is only for local testing. It is for any domain that must be, well, invalid

Comment: Ok I can see why something that looks like it could be a host's name would be disadvantageous to compared to ".".

Comment: @AlphaWhiskey It's _humans_ who can "glance" at something and draw conclusions. Computers need explicit instruction.

Comment: to be fair, it's not exactly hard to give computers explicit instruction in this particular case.

Comment: @res It's even easier *not* to give computers that explicit instruction.

Comment: @musiKk if you don't give it, it ought to just fail *after* doing unnecessary work. "." isn't substantially *less* special-cased here.

Comment: It's easy to make generalizations about what the software "should" do, but in the absence of a standards defining RFC stating that software [MUST](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) do something, it's implementation specific behavior with no assured consistency.

Answer (score 10):

The question as a whole touches on a few different aspects which all need to be taken into consideration to answer why RFC7505 adds something useful.

First of all, the pre-RFC7505 definition of how mail delivery should be made does not have a way to cleanly indicate that no mail delivery attempts should be made for a name which has address records.

From [RFC7505 section 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7505#section-1):

> SMTP clients have a prescribed sequence for identifying a server
> that    accepts email for a domain.  Section 5 of [RFC5321] covers
> this in    detail; in essence, the SMTP client first looks up a DNS MX
> RR, and,    if that is not found, it falls back to looking up a DNS A
> or AAAA RR.    Hence, this overloads a DNS record (that has a
> different primary    mission) with an email service semantic.
>
> If a domain has no MX records, senders will attempt to deliver mail
> to the hosts at the addresses in the domain's A or AAAA records.  If
> there are no SMTP listeners at the A/AAAA addresses, message delivery
> will be attempted repeatedly for a long period, typically a week,
> before the sending Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) gives up.  This will
> delay notification to the sender in the case of misdirected mail and
> will consume resources at the sender.
>
> This document defines a null MX that will cause all mail delivery
> attempts to a domain to fail immediately, without requiring domains
> to create SMTP listeners dedicated to preventing delivery attempts.

Then there's the matter of how RFC7505 implements this (`IN MX 0 .`).

From [RFC7505 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7505#section-3):

> 3. MX Resource Records Specifying Null MX
>
> To indicate that a domain does not accept email, it advertises a
> single MX RR (see Section 3.3.9 of [RFC1035]) with an RDATA section
> consisting of preference number 0 and a zero-length label, written in
> master files as ".", as the exchange domain, to denote that there
> exists no mail exchanger for a domain.  Since "." is not a valid host
> name, a null MX record cannot be confused with an ordinary MX record.
> **The use of "." as a pseudo-hostname meaning no service available is
> modeled on the SRV RR [[RFC2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782#page-4)] where it has a similar meaning.**
>
> A domain that advertises a null MX MUST NOT advertise any other MX
> RR.

(emphasis added)

As is noted here, the implementation details for the "null MX" are based on an already established pattern from the `SRV` RR type. It makes sense to mimic this as the `SRV` RR type more or less is a generalized version of the `MX` RR type.

So, the decision was essentially taken already when defining the [`SRV` RR type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782).

So, why not make use of `.invalid`?

From [RFC2606 section2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2):

> ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain
> names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a
> glance are invalid.

As can be seen here, this reserved TLD is for human consumption. There's no precedent of defining special handling of this in software.

Surely it could have been implemented in some different way but they chose to go with the minimal approach of using `.`, which is not a valid hostname and thus does not interfere with normal use anyway.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no technical reason `.` couldn't have been used as MX record if A or AAAA records had been published at the root. When I type `telnet . 25` it surely does look for A and AAAA records at the root.

Comment: @kasperd While the DNS protocol can surely represent it, I don't believe having address records at `.` or (pre-RFC7505) specifying `.` as the `EXCHANGE` value for an `MX` record would actually be valid. (It's not a valid hostname.)

Comment: Valid or not - I can easily imagine implementations which when faced with an MX record pointing to a domain with no A records will retry delivery for days before giving up.

Comment: “If there are no SMTP listeners” - does this imply that if there are no A or AAAA records, the null MX record is not helpful?

Comment: @twhb If there are no address records (`A`/`AAAA`) and no `MX` records, there would be no place to attempt delivering mail for this domain name anyway (at least based on DNS). Adding a null `MX` for such a domain name would just be making an explicit statement matching what was already the case.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist are you sure that this failure mode does not result in the SMTP agent retrying for a week or so, despite that a reachable IP address with no SMTP server apparently does?

Comment: @twhb This boils down to the ["permanent" vs "transient"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.2.1) error handling in SMTP, where at least the intention is that in a scenario where the domain name has a designated mail server that is unresponsive it's treated as a transient failure (hence why null MX was invented), while a scenario with no designated mail server for a domain name is treated as a permanent error. Ie, just trying to send that mail again won't make a difference, something needs to actually change either with the mail itself or with the recipient side setup.

Comment: @twhb As for whether there is some deviating implementation, I do not know.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist [§4.3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.3.2) seems to specify that an error during connection establishment is a permanent, not temporary, error.

Comment: @twhb Please elaborate. That sounds surprising to me, but I don't know what specifically you refer to.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist §4.3.2, under “CONNECTION ESTABLISHMENT”, specifies the only possible results as 220 (success) or 554. §4.2.1, which you linked, specifies that 5xx codes are permanent failures. §4.5.3.2.1 specifies that there must be a timeout; not what type of error a timeout is, but §4.3.2 permits only 554 or success. §4.2.3 describes 554 in this context as “No SMTP service here”. I see many ways I could have misinterpreted, but on the flip side I’m not seeing anywhere that implies or allows for connection errors being transient, and a quick test resulted in an immediate bounce message.

Comment: @twhb The 554 response referenced there is that something listening may respond 554 as it's initial greeting to indicate it does not accept mail, as discussed in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-3.1

Comment: @twhb I don't know what is the best reference for what you are getting at, but this section at least lays out the overall expectation for handling an unreachable mail server: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.4.1